# C nodes - how to not overwrite the allocated memory space but create new one (homework issue)

Tags: c, arrays, memory, allocation

Company struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct company {
 char* company_name;
 int employee_counter;
} company;
```

I use this function to create a new company node:

```
company *make_company_node(char* company_name, int employee_counter) {
 company *newNode = (company*) malloc(sizeof(company));
 if(!newNode) return NULL; 

 newNode->company_name = company_name;
 newNode->employee_counter = employee_counter;

 return newNode;
}
```

Then I get some company names from the input, create company node for each one:

```
companyUnion->company_arr[i] = make_company_node(company_name, 0);
```

(the company_arr eventually contains pointers to all the companies).

The problem is that it seems I'm always overwriting the originally allocated memory space and therefore at the end I wind up with an array whose cells all point to the last company (with the last name submitted).

How can I correct it so that it doesn't overwrite but instead always allocated new space?

Comment: your code looks ok, are you sure it's not happening due to not properly indexing variables of companyUnion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrm, it seems like the issue is with the `company_name` variable. This is a pointer to the actual data of the company name. How are you allocating this data? Are you sure it's the right pointer? Maybe you need something like this:

```
newNode->company_name = strdup(company_name);
```

`strdup` duplicates the string you pass to it, dynamically. Don't forget to free it.

This is common error because `company_name` contains the address of some data. If the same address is used and the data inside it changes, you end up with different results, therefore you need to make a copy of it.

Comment: I understand now, it did solve the problem. How do I free it though? free(company_name); ? That creates a huge "Memory map" output I don't really need...

Comment: To clean up you need to iterate over your array and do: `free(companyUnion->company_arr[i]->company_name);`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of company_name before calling your `make_company_node` function, I'd change the function to accept that length (use strlen otherwise).

```
company *make_company_node(char *company_name, size_t cn_len, int employee_counter) {
    company *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    if (newNode) {
        newNode->company_name = malloc(cn_len + 1);
        if (newNode->company_name) {
            strcpy(newNode->company_name, company_name);
            newNode->employee_counter = employee_counter;
        } else {
            free(newNode);
            newNode = NULL;
        }
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

I prefer to do it with `malloc` and `strcpy`, instead of `strdup`, because `strdup` is not defined by the Standard (it is defined by POSIX though), and there's no advantage of using `strdup`.

Comment: Using this method do I have to iterate and free the memory?

Comment: Yes, the same as with `strdup`. Otherwise, your best bet is [gen's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417875/c-nodes-how-to-not-overwrite-the-allocated-memory-space-but-create-new-one-hom/4418086#4418086)

Answer (score 1):

If, as pmg mentioned, you know in advance the length of the string or if there is a known maximum number of characters that you can set, prefer defining company_name as a static array instead:

`char company_name[MAX_LENGTH];`

This will reduce the amount of memory management you need to do, along with potential errors as you just experienced.

Comment: +1 for stating the most obvious way to make the program do what the OP wanted in the first place. *Oh! And welcome to SO*

Answer (score 0):

You need to *duplicate* the company_name string:

```
newNode->company_name = strdup(company_name);
```

Don't forget to `free()` it afterwards.